# Delay view render on purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm developing a Rails App who will provided an API that will be used for front-end training purposes.
I'd like to explicitly delay the rendering of the view - any ideas on how can I do this ( without creating an actual performance problem on the server, of course :P )

Comment: You can use jquery `setTimeout` to show the view after specific time.

Comment: Yes. Render the view as a hidden div, then unhide it later with javascript executed on a timer. You don't need jQuery. javascript setTimeout() will work fine. The server is not involved.

Comment: The API will be used by students learning a front-end library. For this reason, the delay must be implemented on the server (so it doesn't introduces anything different on the students development environment)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using #sleep in your controller?

```
# controller
def action
  @model = model.find params[:id]
  sleep(10.seconds)
end
```

Comment: This will tie up an entire thread of execution for the duration of the sleep, and is not advised.

Comment: Exactly. I was looking for a solution that won't cause the application itself to stop executing.